# PayPal smart button transaction showing error

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using PayPal smart button for payments in JavScript. Currently, I am using sandbox accounts to test.

This code gives an error

```
function addPaypal()
{
    
     paypal.Buttons({
    
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
              amount: {
              currency_code:'USD',
                value: '30.00'
              }
            }]
          });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
          console.log(details);
          });
        },
         onCancel: function (data)  {
    
   }, 
  onError: function (err)  {
     console.log(err)
   }
      }).render('#paypal-button'); // Display payment options on your web page  
      
      }
```

The error I am getting is

**details.purchase_units.amount is undefined**

I am using two sandbox accounts. One from which I created an app and using its credentials. And other one from which I am paying the amount for testing.

I checked both accounts. I am not getting more details of the error.

Comment: Tested your purchase_units object at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client and it works, so you'll need to provide more information, or work backwards from that known-working code sample